# LVM volume group not found (debian lenny)

Tags: debian, debian-lenny

Earlier I solved the problem with a kind help :)
[software RAID 1 on Debian - GRUB cursor blinking](https://serverfault.com/questions/170793/software-raid-1-on-debian-grub-cursor-blinking)

I can see the menu and can go into my XP again. However, I am getting error with Debian.

This is what happen with after selecting Debian (from the screen, literally...)

```
Booting 'Debian GNU........ 2.6.26-2-686'
root (hd0,6)
Filesystem type is reiserfs, partition type 0xfd
kernel   /vmlinuz-2.6.26-2.686  root=/dev/mapper/acm_main-root ro quiet
     [Linux-bzImage, setup=0x3000, size=0x16ce500]
initrd  /initrd.img-2.6.26-2.686
     [Linux-initrd @ 0x,....... meaningless here]

Decompressing Linux.... Parising ELF.... done.
Booting the kernel.
[0.244015] PCI: Not using MMCONFIG.
Loading, please wait....
[2.201657] hub 1-:0:1.0: unable to enumerate USB device on port2

madam: /dev/md0 has been started with 2 drives.
madam:  WARNING  /dev/sdb10 and /dev/sda10 appear to have similar superblocks.

     - if they are really different, please --zero the superblock on one
     - if they are the same, or overlap,\please remove one from the DEVICE list in mdadm.conf.
  Volume group "acm_main" not found.

.... After a while....
Gave up waiting for root device. Common problems:
  - Boot args (cat /proc/cmdline)
     - check rootdelay
     - check root (did the system wait for the right device?)
  - Missing modules (cat /proc/modules; ls /dev)
ALERT! /dev/mapper/acm_main-root does not exist. Dropping to a shell!
```

Is this an indication that something goes wrong? Should I reinstall again?

I tried with rescue CD, and using vgscan -v and I only found  acm_tmp, and not acm_main.
I have two volume groups: acm_tmp, and acm_main, where main has the logical groups: /, /home, /usr, /var and tmp has /tmp. Swap is outside

Thank you.

---

**edited**
pvdisplay

```
---Physical Volume ---
PV   Name:   /dev/sda9
VG Name    acm_tmp
PV Size   3.26GB  / not usable 0
Allocatable   yes but full
PE Size  4096
Total PE  835
Free Pe  0
Allocated PE  835
PV UUID    IRGLc1-nUu4-Ckjc0Htf5.... I will stop here

---Physical Volume ---
PV Name:  /dev/sdb9
VG Name:  acm_tmp
.... and the rest are pretty much the same except of course different UUID...
```

I doubled check. That was all I got from the screen.

Did you create your volume groups on top of your RAID device?

> > > How do I know if I did? I am sorry. 
> > >       I actually followed that video. It seems like 
> > >       http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rMyfljiCz3A

---

fdisk -l  (I will skip the Start, End, and Blocks)

```
Disk /dev/sdb: 500.1 GB
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders

Device Boot    ..skip..  Id         System
/dev/sdb1 *               7         HPFS/NTFS
/dev/sdb2                 f         W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sdb5                 7         HPFS/NTFS
/dev/sdb6                 7         HPFS/NTFS
/dev/sdb7 *               fd        Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sdb8                 82        Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sdb9                 8e        Linux LVM
/dev/sdb10                fd        Linux raid autodetect
```

In addition, the problem we solved last time ....
I had partition num: 6  for reiserfs, partition type 0xfd
It looks very correspondence to the above

```
possible partitions are
partition num: 0, Filesystem type unknown, type 0x7
num 4: same as num0
num 5: same as num0
num 6: reiserfs
num 7: filesystem unknown, type 0x82
num 8: type 0x8e
num 9: 0xfd
```

Comment: What does pvdisplay show you? Also, did you create your volume groups on top of your RAID device?

Comment: hi vmfarms, thank you for your kind help.  i edited the post with pvdisplay....

Comment: Could you also provide the output of: fdisk -l
This will help determine how the partition layout looks like.

Comment: hi vmfarms, thank you. i provided them already. i gave you fdisk -l and root (hd0, tab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I see what the problem is. It appears that your acm_root Volume Group sits on the second RAID array, which is having trouble starting due to this error:

```
madam: /dev/md0 has been started with 2 drives.
madam:  WARNING  /dev/sdb10 and /dev/sda10 appear to have similar superblocks.

     - if they are really different, please --zero the superblock on one
     - if they are the same, or overlap,\please remove one from the DEVICE list in mdadm.conf.
```

To fix this, boot into rescue mode once again, and run the following (as suggested):

```
mdadm --zero-superblock /dev/sda10
```

Then try booting again. Hope this helps.

Comment: hi vmfarms. it works! may i ask how should i install the system in the future, if you just have a little more time? thank you!

Comment: I've looked at the video you sent, and it seems pretty straightforward. It may have been caused by the fact that you have both a Windows and Linux partition on the same drive, and the instructions only account for Linux. In the future to make things easier, I would put Windows on a separate drive entirely. Good Luck!